# Create Comment box in Javascript without any server side coding

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am new to web development, i need to develop a comment box, and save those comments in a file( either database or normal text pad), so that i can retrieve them later and display them on my web. The comments should be seen on web page even after refreshing the page.
Server side programming should not be used.so i believe that i have to code in javascript, can anyone please help me with the code for doing this, as to how to implement a comment box and save the comments in file using javascript.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why without server coding?

Comment: Then you have got only one option to store in local storage, but then user can delete it as well as you have limited space

Comment: How do you plan to access a database without SS coding? Thats like driving a car without an engine...

Comment: @Edward flinstones :P

Comment: Have you thought about pen and paper? That doesn't use SS coding either...

Comment: i thought of doing it using localstorage in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you would also like other users (other than you - the visitor, creator of a comment) to see the comments. Unfortunately, you can't achieve this without server-side code. The comments have to be stored somewhere on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save programmatically anything to file within local filesystem without user participation - this is security limitation. You can use, for example, cookies instead, or any other local storage techniques. But without server-side only you will be able to see your comments.